# Alternatives for HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse in Micronaut

Tags: java, kotlin, micronaut

I am playing with Micronaut and what I currently miss is access to `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`. These normally allow to access things like:

- request parameters
- input/output stream (especially writing directly to output stream)
- getting/setting cookies
- getting/setting headers
- getting client IP

Also I am not sure about alternatives for:

- `@RequestParam files: List<MultipartFile>`
- `@RequestBody myClass: MyClass`

Comment: There is `io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest`

Comment: I noticed, but I didn't find a way to correctly get all the things which I described.

Comment: There is `io.micronaut.http.FullHttpRequest` ...?

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't have neither InputStream, nor OutputStream on FullHttpResponse.

Comment: "input/output stream (especially writing directly to output stream)" Return a reactive stream to achieve this. Micronaut is non blocking so streams are not used like how they are in the servlet world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#requestResponse and https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#binding shows how to bind to request parameters, cookies, headers, etc.

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#uploads shows how to handle file uploads.

> input/output stream (especially writing directly to output stream)

Micronaut does things differently so you don't have access to a stream to write to. You can return a reactive type to have your data pushed to the response as soon as it's available.

> getting client IP

Typically available via the host header or https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/HttpRequest.html#getRemoteAddress--

Edit: Sending an XML file chunked

```
@Get(uri = "/xml", produces = MediaType.TEXT_XML)
Flowable<String> getXml() {
    return Flowable.create(emitter -> {
        emitter.onNext("<<xml header>>");
        //do some work
        emitter.onNext("more xml");
        emitter.onNext("<<xml footer>>");
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
}
```

Comment: How the input/output stream are ahndled differently? Can you give specific example how to do that?

Comment: @Vojtěch Can you give a specific example of what you want to send?

Comment: For instance, I want to send parts of XML files, start with xml header, than some body parts and when finished, send XML footer.

Comment: @Vojtěch I've added an example

Answer (score 1):

@RequestBody -> @Body (https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#bodyAnnotation)

@RequestParam -> @QueryValue

https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-spring/latest/guide/index.html

Comment: thanks, I managed to find the `@Body` annotation already, `@QueryValue` I knew before and wasn't part of my question. However the rest of the question remains unanswered.

Comment: will give you the detailed implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Filter](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#transfers) for using HTTP request/response

```
@Singleton
public class TraceService {

Flowable<Boolean> yourFilter(HttpRequest<?> request) {
```

> The Micronaut HTTP server supports the ability to apply filters to request/response processing in a similar, but reactive, way to Servlet filters in traditional Java applications.
>
> Filters provide the ability to support the following use cases:
>
> Decoration of the incoming HttpRequest
>
> Modification of the outgoing HttpResponse

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I got stuck with this problem tonight but there's a way around it.

Create a generic Bean that stores a HttpHeaders property.

```
public class HttpHeaderHolder {
    private HttpHeaders headers;

    public HttpHeaderHolder() {
    }

    public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
        return headers;
    }

    public void setHeaders(HttpHeaders headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
    }

}
```

Once you have this, create a Factory that creates a RequestScoped bean of that class.

```
@Factory
public class HttpHeaderFactory {

    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    public HttpHeaderHolder requestHeaders() {
        return new HttpHeaderHolder();
    }

}
```

Now, you can make a Filter that has this bean injected to which to can then inject the headers from the request.

```
@Filter("/**")
public class SomeFilter implements HttpFilter {
    @Inject
    private HttpHeaderHolder instance;

    @Override
    public Publisher<? extends HttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> request, FilterChain chain) {
        instance.setHeaders(request.getHeaders());
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }

}
```

Now you have a bean you can inject into anywhere to get the headers for the current request.  It seems to work because the filter will intercept the request and push the HttpHeaders into the bean before reaching the Controllers.